# Sorting list thats populated in another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am populating a list in Thread A and sorting it in Thread B.

```
 var SortedListByDistance = Distancelist.OrderBy(o => o._Distance).Where(o => o.Distance <= _Distance).ToList();
```

Now I am getting following error:

> Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and
>   the array's lower bounds.

Doing some research on Google I came across "Thread safe" topics. Basically list is being locked(?) in another thread and exception is fired.

This at least is how I understand it. Now the question is how can I avoid the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you cannot lock a `List<T>` in a way, that no-one can use it in that time. But you can create two blocks of code, which lock out the other one (Mutual Exclusion).
So you could use something like

```
lock(Distancelist) {
    var SortedListByDistance = Distancelist.OrderBy(o => o._Distance).Where(o => o.Distance <= _Distance).ToList();
}
```

Where you'd need to lock the same object in your Thread A, to implement the mutual exclusion.

PS: It is discouraged to lock the objects you actually want to use for several reasons. The cleaner way would be to use another object, like `object Distancelist_sync = new object()` which then is used for locking.

Comment: I agree with you regarding locking on a different object - which makes me wonder why you started with showing locking the list and adding a PS for another object. Wouldn't it be better to present it the other way around, i.e. show how to lock on another object and if need be, a PS with "you can also lock on the list itself, but it is discouraged"

Comment: If and why another object should be used seems to be highly discussed. I didn't want the answer to be declared as wrong just because of that discussion, so I excluded that point. I think the OP used the list for locking, why I wanted to present the "solution-strategy" in 2 separated steps.

Comment: In this case, `DistanceList` is capitalised which strongly indicates that it is public, and therefore as Patrik says, should not be locked upon.

Comment: Thanks for providing me with both solutions. I think i will have to go with second part of posted solution.